# Unable to disable/uninstall Hyper-V

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

I have an issue trying to uninstall Hyper-V in Windows 8.1 update 1.
I installed Visual Studio 2013 and Hyper-V came with this installation.
Now, I'm unable to disable it in the "Windows Functionality" panel: when I uncheck the Hyper-V box, it ask me to reboot and then (when the machine is powering up), it says to me that it's impossibile to install the updates, rollback of the modifies...".

How can I solve this? Is there another way to uninstall this service?

Thanks for all the time and the support.

Luca

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip the folder and upload the folder to a cloud service and share the link to it here. I'll take a look at them to see why the configuration fails.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this "issue". The problem was that I tryed to disabled Hyper-V with Powershell and CMD command both. I just rehabilitated it on both Powershell and CMD (maybe useless doing it in both ways) and then rebooted